# Is there a python function for finding the numeric and categorical columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories, numeric

What is an efficient way of splitting/returning the categorical columns and numeric columns from the pandas data frame in python?

So far I'm using the below function for finding the categorical columns and numeric columns.

```
def returnCatNumList(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int', 'float', 'int64', 'float64', 
                                                 'int32', 'float32', 'int16', 'float16']).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float', 'int64', 'float64', 
                                                  'int32', 'float32', 'int16', 'float16']).columns)

    return object_cols, numeric_cols
```

I'm looking for an efficient and better approach to do this. Any suggestions or references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your answer by `np.number` instead list of numeric `dtype`s:

```
def returnCatNumList(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

    return object_cols, numeric_cols
```

Another idea is for `numeric_cols` use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
def returnCatNumList(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.columns.difference(object_cols, sort=False))

    return object_cols, numeric_cols
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using object dtype

```
def returnCatNumList(df):
    
    object_cols = df.select_dtypes(include="object").columns.tolist()
    numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude="object").columns.tolist()

    return object_cols, numeric_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the [pandas types API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#data-types-related-functionality) which allows us to interact and manipulate the types of data

```
def returnCatNumList(df):
    object_cols = []
    numeric_cols  = []

    for label, content in df.items():
        if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(content):
            numeric_cols.append(label)
        else:
            object_cols.append(label)
    return object_cols, numeric_cols
```

Example:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

object_cols, numeric_cols = returnCatNumList(iris)

print(object_cols)
print(numeric_cols)
```

output:

```
>>> ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']

>>> ['species']
```